Flutter launchUrl not launching despite canLaunchUrl returning true on Linux Ubuntu 20.04 app
I am trying to launch a url via a button on Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.4, on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS 5.15.0-122-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8) for a Linux application. The check for canLaunchUrl passes, but no url actually gets launched on my browser.
I have tried reinstalling vscode, flutter SDK, changing networks, and switching to the deprecated launch and canLaunch functions. At the moment, I am trying by hardcoding google as the url.
Example of function and prints to show code flow
flutter doctor -vv output:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.4, on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS 5.15.0-122-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 3.16.4 on channel stable at /home/uei-sm-test/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 2e9cb0aa71 (10 months ago), 2023-12-11 14:35:13 -0700
    • Engine revision 54a7145303
    • Dart version 3.2.3
    • DevTools version 2.28.4

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.


[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
    • cmake version 3.16.3
    • ninja version 1.10.0
    • pkg-config version 0.29.1

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] VS Code (version 1.93.1)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.98.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Linux (desktop) • linux  • linux-x64      • Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS 5.15.0-122-generic
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 127.0.6533.88

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
uei-sm-test@uei-sm-test-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-7th:~/src/qse_sample_app-qsra/modules/image_display/src$ flutter doctor -vv
[  +36 ms] Unable to locate an Android SDK.
[   +9 ms] executing: uname -m
[  +13 ms] Exit code 0 from: uname -m
[        ] x86_64
[  +96 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LegacyCanvasKitRemover' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +113 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MaterialFonts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'GradleWrapper' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LegacyCanvasKitRemover' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +20 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +5 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FontSubsetArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'PubDependencies' is not required, skipping update.
[ +283 ms] executing: [/home/uei-sm-test/snap/flutter/common/flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[   +7 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[        ] 10 months ago
[ +101 ms] [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.4, on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS 5.15.0-122-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[   +2 ms]     • Flutter version 3.16.4 on channel stable at /home/uei-sm-test/snap/flutter/common/flutter
[        ]     • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[        ]     • Framework revision 2e9cb0aa71 (10 months ago), 2023-12-11 14:35:13 -0700
[        ]     • Engine revision 54a7145303
[        ]     • Dart version 3.2.3
[        ]     • DevTools version 2.28.4
[  +17 ms] [✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
[        ]     ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
[        ]       Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
[        ]       On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
[        ]       (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).
[        ]       If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
[        ]       `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.
[  +11 ms] [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[        ]     • Chrome at google-chrome
[ +402 ms] [✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[        ]     • clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
[  +21 ms]     • cmake version 3.16.3
[   +8 ms]     • ninja version 1.10.0
[        ]     • pkg-config version 0.29.1
[   +3 ms] [!] Android Studio (not installed)
[        ]     • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
[        ]       (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).
[   +4 ms] [✓] VS Code (version 1.93.1)
[        ]     • VS Code at /usr/share/code
[        ]     • Flutter extension version 3.98.0
[   +2 ms] [✓] Connected device (2 available)
[        ]     • Linux (desktop) • linux  • linux-x64      • Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS 5.15.0-122-generic
[  +20 ms]     • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 127.0.6533.88
[   +5 ms] [✓] Network resources
[   +4 ms]     • All expected network resources are available.
[   +1 ms] ! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
[  +29 ms] "flutter doctor" took 1,101ms.
[ +196 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 123ms
[        ] Running 0 shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 0

Button widget and function:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class LaunchUrlButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String url;
  const LaunchUrlButton({super.key, required this.url});

  Future<void> _launchUrl(String url) async {
    print('pressed with url $url');
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    if (!await canLaunchUrl(uri)) {
      print('attempting to launch url $url');
      await launchUrl(uri);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        child: IconButton(
          style: const ButtonStyle(),
          icon: const Icon(Icons.link),
          onPressed: () {
            _launchUrl(url);
          },
        ));
  }
}


Your canLaunchUrl check seems suspicious - I think you're improperly negating it, it should be just if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)).

Thanks, I'll try it and let you know how it goes
